# Calling "Campaign Manager 360 API -> conversions.batchinsert " and getting all the time the error "code": "NOT_FOUND"

Tags: google-api

- I am trying to create conversions using "Method: conversions.batchinsert" from the API Explorer provided by google on the same API page.
- I do not why I am getting the error with code 200

````
Request
{
  "kind": "dfareporting#conversionsBatchInsertRequest",
  "conversions": [
    {
      "timestampMicros": "1635788776043000",
      "ordinal": "1635788776043000",
      "kind": "dfareporting#conversion",
      "floodlightConfigurationId": "12067120",
      "floodlightActivityId": "11765909",
      "dclid": "testdclid"
    }
  ]
}

Response
{
  "hasFailures": true,
  "status": [
    {
      "conversion": {
        "floodlightConfigurationId": "12067120",
        "floodlightActivityId": "11765909",
        "timestampMicros": "1635788776043000",
        "ordinal": "1635788776043000",
        "kind": "dfareporting#conversion",
        "dclid": "testdclid"
      },
      "errors": [
        {
          "code": "NOT_FOUND",
          "message": "",
          "kind": "dfareporting#conversionError"
        }
      ],
      "kind": "dfareporting#conversionStatus"
    }
  ],
  "kind": "dfareporting#conversionsBatchInsertResponse"
}
```
````

Comment: Would you mind giving me the link to the api you are trying to use?  [this maybe](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/rest/v3.5/conversions/batchinsert)

Comment: Are you aware that the Campaign Manager 360 API v3.4 is deprecated and will be sunset on Jan 10th, 2022?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/rest/v3.5/conversions/batchinsert

Comment: I am also getting a similar error, any update to this?